# How to show only last 6 months on morris.js chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, morris.js

I am using morris line chart to display data based on last one year.I am able to display it successfully.
Now my requirement is changed and I need to display data based on last 6 months.Is there any way in morris.js chart where I can show only last 6 months on x axis ?